# Getting system's time

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I want to store data of sold items into database I'm using this stored procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[StoredProd]
(@prdctName nvarchar(50),
 @ordrdQnty int,
 @ordrPrice money,
 --@TrnId int,
 --@OrdrId int,
 @TrnDate datetime,
 @TrnTotal money)

AS BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [OrderProduct]
           ([prdctName]
           ,[ordrdQnty]
           ,[ordrPrice])
     VALUES
           (@prdctName,
            @ordrdQnty, 
            @ordrPrice )
           --GETDATE() ),
if @@ERROR<>0 goto Err_

INSERT INTO [Transaction]
           (/*[TrnId]
           ,[OrdrId],*/
           [TrnDate]
           ,[TrnTotal])
     VALUES
           (/*@TrnId, 
           @OrdrId,*/
          (SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
           @TrnTotal)

           if @@ERROR<>0 goto Err_

commit tran
return 0

Err_:
rollback
return 1

enter code here
```

This C# Code

```
  private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            string conn = "server=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=PharmacyDB;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvSelectedItem.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedP");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prdctName", dgvSelectedItem.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ordrdQnty", dgvSelectedItem.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ordrPrice", dgvSelectedItem.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));


                con.ConnectionString = conn;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

            }
```

---

I have 2 tables and this SP should stored the OrderProduct table data first then filling Transaction table the relationship between them is many orders to one Transaction ID , but  this error is appeared:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Procedure or function 'storedP' expects parameter '@TrnDate', which was not supplied.

Comment: C# code? From error message it seems you simply don't provide TrnDate parameter but if you posted this question probably it's not so easy...

Comment: I'm sorry , but I don't understand what do you want to say..

Comment: Gordon Linoff if you mean that I shouldn't declare @TrnDate parameter , I've tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Another issue: You don't need CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Use GETDATE(), which you actually used but it's commented out.

Comment: I faced the same error with GETDATE()

Comment: I mean: show us your c# code. Error is there.

Comment: I added C# code, I want to fill 2 tables at the same time one after the other ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  The problem is your calling the stored procedure not the code itself.  The stored procedure has the following definition:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[StoredProd] (
    @prdctName nvarchar(50),
    @ordrdQnty int,
    @ordrPrice money,
    @TrnDate datetime,
    @TrnTotal money
) . . .
```

It is expecting five arguments, one of which is `@TrnDate` (positionally, this should be the fourth).  You don't seem to be including that argument, and you are getting an error on the stored procedure call itself.

EDIT:

If you want `@TrnDate` to default to the system time, then use `default`:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[StoredProd] (
    @prdctName nvarchar(50),
    @ordrdQnty int,
    @ordrPrice money,
    @TrnDate datetime default getdate(),
    @TrnTotal money
) . . .
```

If you don't want it as a parameter, remove it entirely.  You can `declare` it in the body of the stored procedure:

```
declare @TrnDate datetime = getdate();
```

Comment: If you mean that I shouldn't declare @TrnDate parameter , I've tried that but it doesn't work –

Comment: @user3423060 . . . Your calling code needs to add the parameters  `@TrnDate` and `@TrnTotal`.  Or, these need to be given default values in the stored procedure.  Or, removed entirely from the stored procedure interface.

Comment: I want @TrnDate to give me the system time

Comment: Thank you it works , now I will try to count the total.